# Convex hull area of projected points are convex respect to rotations?

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

Let $A$ be a finite list of points in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $c$ the centroid of $A$. Let $P$ be an orthographic projection onto a plane in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $h$ be the convex hull of $P(A)$. Let further $|h|$ be the area of the convex hull on the 2D plain.

Theorem to proof: the function of $|h|$ that arises if $A$ is rotated around $c$ about $0\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $0\leq\phi<2\pi$ is convex.

Is it true, or partly true? Do you have an idea how a proof roughly looks like?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Consider a prism with regular 8-gon as a base. When you rotate it by $\frac{\pi}{8}$ (from green to blue) the area gets smaller, and with next $\frac{\pi}{8}$ (from blue to green) the projection gets bigger again.

[image: 8gon]

The $|h|$ won't be convex nor concave, it will look like a wave, but with sharp corners, very similar to [cycloid](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycloid), that is

[image: func].

I hope this helps ;-)

Comment: thank's a lot. you're right. cool illustration :)